# jQuery canvasjs donut chart realtime retrieve data

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, canvasjs

I'm using [Donut Chart](https://canvasjs.com/jquery-charts/doughnut-chart/)

And retrieve the data from database through PHP.

PHP

```
$q = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT DESCRIPTION, SUM(QUANTITY) AS TOTALS FROM TEST1 
GROUP BY DESCRIPTION");
oci_execute($q);
while($d = oci_fetch_array($q))
{
    $description[] = $d['DESCRIPTION'];
    $quantity[] = $d['TOTALS'];

    $nameAndCode = array();
    $nameAndCode['label'] = $d['DESCRIPTION'];
    $nameAndCode['y'] = $d['TOTALS'];           
    $namesArray[] = $nameAndCode;
}

$dataPoints = array(
    "dataPoints"     => $namesArray
);

echo json_encode($dataPoints);
```

And JS

```
var dataPoints = [];

function updateChart()
{
    $.getJSON("data.php", function(result)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i <= result.dataPoints.length - 1; i++)
        {
            dataPoints.push({
                label: result.dataPoints[i].label,
                y: parseInt(result.dataPoints[i].y)
            });
        }

        chart.render();
    });
}

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    data: [{
    type: "doughnut",
    innerRadius: "40%",
    showInLegend: true,
    legendText: "{label}",
    indexLabel: "{label}: #percent%",
    dataPoints: dataPoints
    }]
});

var updateInterval = 1000;

setInterval(function(){
    updateChart()
}, updateInterval);
```

When I tried to run the code, the Donut Chart will always show so many duplicate. Data retrieve only 4 items.

[image]

[image]

My purpose is Donut Chart will always realtime to get data.

My question, how to prevent so many duplicate chart?

[image]

Comment: The 'GROUP BY' clause should be preventing that. I'd suggest debugging your query to see why it's not working

Comment: The query is working good. I tried on TOAD and it show me 4 items. Btw I'm using `setInterval` on JS function to retrieve every second

Comment: That in itself is a bad idea. If you want to keep the UI in sync with the data on the server, use WebSockets or Server Sent Events. If you have to use polling, chain the requests instead of using an interval, as the latter can cause requests to back up and flood your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first empty the dataPoints array when you get the result and then you should iterate through it to populate.

Try something like;

```
$.getJSON("data.php", function(result)
    {
        $("#chartContainer").options.data[0].dataPoints = result;
        $("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart().render();
    });
```

Example;
https://jsfiddle.net/yumn325w/

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Try emptying the chart *before* adding the data, not after.

Comment: @Neil do you mean outside `$.getJSON("data.php", function(result)` ?

Comment: @HiDayurieDave No, I mean as suggested by Umur.

Comment: @Neil just now tried and it's fixed, but if there is new data, the chart is not update automatically

Comment: @HiDayurieDave Just because you don't see a change to the data *does not mean it is not being updated*.  Check your network tab of your browser.  If you're seeing regular requests, it may very well be updating anyway.

Comment: So is it correct right now ? I edited the explanation to be more clear

Comment: @Neil Please have a look on my question again.

Comment: @UmurAlpay that screenshot code it not working, no chart appear

Comment: @UmurAlpay just now tried and it still not show the chart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183358/discussion-between-umur-alpay-and-hidayurie-dave).

Answer (score 0):

Delete and ReCreate Chart Container (CANVAS) every time

```
    function updateChart()
    {
       document.getElementById("divDonutChart").innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
       document.getElementById("divDonutChart").innerHTML = '<canvas 
       id="chartContainer"> </canvas>  ';

        $.getJSON("data.php", function(result)
        {
```